# Normal approximation of binomial distribution involving o-notation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I've got a binomial distributed random variable X where $p = \frac{1}{2}$, so that $P(X \leq \frac{n}{2} + o(\sqrt{n})) = \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}+o(\sqrt{n})}\binom{n}{i}(\frac{1}{2})^n$ and the standard deviation is $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}$.

Now it says that the normal approximation to the binomial distribution yields that this probability is $\frac{1}{2}+o(1)$.

I'm wondering how this approximation works in detail. Anyone who could explain how to come up with the latter probability?

Comment: In the context of this question, what is the "it" in "it says"?

Comment: @kimchilover It's a book in which they argue that what I've written does hold, namely "Finite Automata, Formal Logic, and Circuit Complexity", pages 149-150.

Comment: Do you know the classical [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT) ?  Your result follows directly from it, with a small end-game argument.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, but what I get from that is that $\sqrt{n}(S_n - \frac{1}{2}) \rightarrow N(0, \frac{n}{4})$ (since $\mu = \frac{1}{2}$ in our case). And it irritates me that we have $P(X \leq \frac{n}{2} + o(\sqrt{n}))$ and not $P(X \leq z)$ for some real number $z$. 
I don't know how to proceed with what we have so far in order to reach what is claimed to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central limit theorem tells us that if $X_n\sim\mbox{Bin}(n,1/2)$ then for each fixed $x$ we have 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} P\left( \frac{ X_n-n/2}{\sqrt{n/4}}\le x\right) = \Phi(x),$$
where we make use of the facts that $EX_n=n/2$ and $\mbox{SD}(X_n)=\sqrt{(1/2)(1/2)n}$.

As originally phrased the question asks for a proof that $$P(X_n\le \frac n 2 + o(\sqrt n) = \frac 1 2 + o(1).$$ This is the same[see footnote below]  as asking if, whenever $e_n$ is such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}e_n=0$, it follows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(X_n\le n/2+e_n\sqrt n)=1/2.$$  That is, if $e_n\to0$ implies $P(X_n\le n/2+e_n\sqrt n)\to1/2$.

You are interested in the event $A_n = [X_n\le n/2+e_n\sqrt n]$.  For each $\epsilon>0$ we know $|e_n \sqrt n|<\epsilon\sqrt n/2$ for all $n$ sufficiently large.  For such $n$ we have the following containment of events:
$$ [X_n\le n/2-\epsilon\sqrt n/2]\subseteq A_n\subseteq  [X_n\le n/2+\epsilon\sqrt n/2].$$
The CLT, applied to the left-hand event and right-hand events gives $$\Phi(-\epsilon)\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)$$ and
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)\le \Phi(\epsilon).$$

Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, and $\Phi$ is continuous at $0$, this implies $$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)=\Phi(0)=\frac 1 2,$$
which is another way of saying $P(A_n)=1/2+o(1).$

Note: recall, from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation) or a_n=[here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/little-oh-notation-o) that to say $a_n=o(b_n)$ is to say (for nonzero $b_n$, at least) that $a_n/b_n\to 0$; in the special case $b_n=1$ we have $a_n=o(1)$ is the same as $a_n/(1) \to 0$, that is, $a_n\to0$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, kimchi lover! 
Could you please explain to me, 
1) why in the second line of your answer there's the $\sqrt{n/4}$ in the denominator? As I wrote in the comment above, I thought that we have $\sqrt{n}$ in the numerator? 

2) Why is $|o(\sqrt{n})| < \sqrt{n}\epsilon$ and not $\leq$? 

3) With "containment" you mean that the probability of the event listed first is smaller than the one of $A_n$, which is smaller than the one of the third event? 

4) Why do you have $\Phi(x+\epsilon)$ and not $\Phi(\epsilon)$ in the lim sup? 

5) Where does the o(1) come into play?

Comment: I have addressed your points 1, 4 (which was my typo), and 5 in edits to my answer.  For 2: your comment is wrong.  Redo the scaling calculations to see why.  As for 3:  if $A\subset B\subset C$ then $P(A)\le P(B)\le P(C)$.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections and information! In your edit, shouldn't it be the standard deviation instead of the variance? 5) With "another way of saying" you mean, because we consider the limit, the error can only be in o(1)? 2) What do you mean by "redoing the scaling"? 3) I'm aware of that implication. But does the implication in the opposite direction also hold? I mean, how do we know that for our events A, B and C (where $B =A_n$) it holds that $A \subset B \subset C$? (It's clear to me that for our events it's the case that $P(A) \leq P(B) \leq P(C)$.)

Comment: You are right about SD versus variance; thank you for bearing with my typos.  As for the containment:  Any value of $X_n$ such that $A$ happens will be so small that $B$ must also happen, and any value of $X_n$ such that $B$ happens will not be so large that $C$ won't happen.  If $n$ is sufficiently large. that is.

Comment: Thank you, kimchi! Now I've nearly understood it, only my questions regarding 2) and 5) as in my last comment are still open. Could you please answer them, too?

Comment: Can you spell out just what your 2) and 5) concerns are?  I think your 2) has something to do with an otherwise undefined $S_n$ you brought up in a comment, and 5) hinges on your not understanding that $\lim a_n = 1/2 $ means the same thing as $a_n=1/2+o(1)$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't understand that one regarding 5). I assume that approximation is the case in general? 
2) was that I don't see why $|o(\sqrt{n})| < \sqrt{n}\epsilon$. You've now avoided this statement in your answer post, but I'd still be interested in why this does hold. 
Regarding you edit, I there's now the additional question why you can substitute $o(\sqrt{n})$ by $e_n \sqrt{n}$ for some $e_n$ with $lim_n e_n = 0$?

Comment: The _meaning_ of $a_n=o(\sqrt n)$ is that $a_n/\sqrt n\to 0$.  So if you define $e_n=a_n/\sqrt n$, then the conclusion that $e_n\to 0$ should be obvious.

Comment: Yes, thank you, kimchi lover! And thanks for your patience :)

Comment: Hi kimchi lover, I'm sorry, but I still haven't understood the substitution of $lim \, P\left(X_n \leq \frac{n}{2} + o(\sqrt{n}) \right) = \frac{n}{2} + o(1)$ with $lim \,P\left(X_n \leq \frac{n}{2} + e_n \sqrt{n}\right) = \frac{n}{2}$. 
Why does the o(1) vanish and why is demanding $e_n \rightarrow 0$ enough? (I understood that $e_n \rightarrow 0$ follows from defining $e_n := \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{n}}$, but we didn't define $e_n$ as the latter and we can't since we don't know the specific $a_n$.

Comment: The _meaning_ (or +definition_ ) of $o(1)$ is that it converges to $0$, the _meaning_ of $A_n = 1/2+o(1)$ is that $\lim_n A_n = 1/2$.